# Duplicate DOM nodes in JS

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the duplication of a div. 
I created a loop to duplicate the star system in all answers. But when I try to append the block and the console return me an error function.

```
function insertStarSystem() {
     var targetFaq = document.getElementById('faq');
     var targetPanel = targetFaq.getElementsByClassName('panel');
```

I targeted the div:

```
    if (targetPanel.length > 0) {
         for (var i = 0; i < targetPanel.length; i++) {
              var star = document.getElementById('star_rating');
              star.style.display = 'inherit';

              $(targetPanel[i]).append(star);
         }
     }
}
```

Here is the div "star_rating":

```
<div id="star_rating" class="display">  
            <fieldset id='system_rating' class="rating alert" >
            <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="Rating5" value="5"/>
            <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Au Top!"></label>
            <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4"/>
            <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Carrément!"></label>
            <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3"/>
            <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Presque!"></label>
            <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2"/>
            <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Un Peu!"></label>
            <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1"/>
            <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Pas du tout!"></label>
        </div>
```

You can see in the code above, I tried to duplicate the the `star_rating` for all answers. But it returns only one `star_system` in the last answer. What am I doing wrong?

```
 <div class="panel panel-primary padding txtLeft">
     <legend>Combien l'installation va-t-elle me coûter ?</legend>
 </div>
```

And I have 4 div like that, I want to duplicate my system in each div

Comment: You can't have duplicate Ids. Rule number 1 of HTML.

Comment: If I replace the div by a class, you think thats resolve the problem ?

Comment: where is the `panel` className in your HTML ?

Comment: It's unlikely causing the issue, but the naming of the radio buttons is not consistent. star5 is named Rating5

Comment: The panel className isn't here, it's just my answer structure, I will put an exemple to show you the panel

Comment: Thx i will change the names

Comment: the fieldset isn't closed properly

Comment: Thx to see that, I closing him

Comment: _“and the console return me an error”_ - what error? It absolutely doesn’t help that you vaguely mention an error - please always quote error messages verbatim! (And also explicitly say which part of the code they are referring to, in case that is not obvious, line numbers don’t match shortened code, etc.)

Comment: _“But it returns only one star_system in the last answer. What am I doing wrong?”_ - you are not actually “duplicating” anything here, you are just moving the existing element around - because that’s what `append` does; if the element already exists on the DOM, then it will just be _moved_ to the new location. You need to create _clones_ of the element first, if you want to keep the original in its place.

Comment: my loop dont duplicate the star_system ?

Comment: You are not duplicating anything in the code posted here

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). You **aren't duplicating anything**. I don't know what made you think you are.

`append` without cloning will only move that element from parent to parent without cloning it (obviously). you did not expect `append` to magically clone nodes for you, no? it's a very basic DOM method that does what it says it does:

Append `X` into `Y`. if `X` is appended to many places (in a loop in your case) than it's the same `X` all the time, being moved around.

### Fixed code:

```
if (targetPanel.length > 0) {
     for (var i = 0; i < targetPanel.length; i++) {
          var starClone = document.getElementById('star_rating').cloneNode(true);
          starClone.style.display = 'inherit';

          $(targetPanel[i]).append( starClone );  
     }
 }
```

> As mentioned in the main comments, you cannot have in one document
>   more than a single unique `ìd` attribute, so you need to get that
>   fixed. Just stop using `ìd` attributes until you master things.

---

I also don't know what why are you mixing jQuery code and vanilla code..since you did not tag `jQuery` in the question. very odd.